# Cordova missing error throw when writing to application directory

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, fileapi

According to the cordova-plugin-file api , https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file ,the cordova.file.application directory is readOnly, and this makes sense. What does not make sense however is that initializing a file writer on a FileEntry object referencing a file inside the application directory does not throw an error. It also does not appear to write to a file either thankfully, but there should still be an error thrown correct?

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the way the api works?

```
function write(json, callBack){
    var retVal = "";
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"www/fooFiles/foo.txt", function(fileEntry){
                console.log(fileEntry);

                fileEntry.file(function(file){
                    console.log("got file");
                    console.log(file);
                    /*an error should be thrown here*/          
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

                        //fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);

                        var blob = new Blob(["testing this used to be json"], {type:'text/plain'});
                        fileWriter.write(blob);
                        console.log("success");
                        retVal=true;
                        callBack(retVal);
                    }, function(){
                        console.log("File write failed");
                        retVal=false;
                        callBack(retVal);
                    });
                }, function(error){
                    console.log("Error getting file");
                    console.log(error);
                });

            });
}
```

Comment: Please read the docs where you can save files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: If you think you should get an error, file an issue on issues.cordova.io